# Apache Redirect If Contains String

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying:

```
RewriteRule ^\/product\/id\/7$ http://newdomain.com/whywonthisworkgrrr?id=1 [L,R=301]
```

And it won't work, I need to redirect all pages that have /product/id/7 anywhere in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

> `need to redirect all pages that have /product/id/7 anywhere in the URL.`

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule (^|/)product/id/7(/|$) http://newdomain.com/whywonthisworkgrrr?id=1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess and what URL did you use to test?

Comment: It is located in the root directory of the website. The actual URL doesn't relate to a physical folder on the server.

Comment: Ok what exactly is the URL are you trying, you can mask your real domain name.

Comment: I am trying http://domain.com/product/id/7 and it isn't redirecting. And yes my other redirects are.